# Adding meta tags to wordpress REST api response

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I am trying to add a custom field to my GET response through the WordPress REST API but I can not seem to get the custom field to show up.

Here is my code so far

```
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'create_api_posts_meta_field' );

    function create_api_posts_meta_field() {

     // register_rest_field ( 'name-of-post-type', 'name-of-field-to-return', array-of-callbacks-and-schema() )
     register_rest_field( 'post', 'post-meta-fields', array(
     'get_callback' => 'get_post_meta_for_api',
     'schema' => null,)
     );
}
function get_post_meta_for_api( $object ) {
 //get the id of the post object array
 $post_id = $object['id'];

 //return the post meta
 return get_post_meta( $post_id,true );
}
```

I have tried adding this code as a custom plugin and also into my functions.php.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

> get_post_meta( $post_id, true )

to:

> get_post_meta( $post_id,'meta_field', true ) // returns a single field

or:

> get_post_meta( $post_id) // returns all the meta data